# Setup database mirroring on linux

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, partitioning

Hi Anyone help me the below question

Can we set up database mirroring on Linux in SQL Server Standard Edition?

Comment: SQL Server version? Do you mean the actual mirroring feature in SQL Server (which is deprecated) or do you mean it in a general sense and are looking for any kind of data synchronization feature?